# How do you fetch a cursor variable multiple times

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, plsqldeveloper

I am passing a cursor as input parameter in a function.

```
  Function (p_cur IN curType) ...

  Loop (outer loop)

      Loop (inner loop)

      fetch p_cur into p_cur_rec;
      exit when p_cur%notfound;

        do some processing here...

      end loop;

   END Loop;
```

The inner loop fetches all the cursor records and i was able to go through each iteration to process the data.

However, when the outer loop fetches the 2nd record, the inner loop doesn't seem to fetch from the cursor again. It appears the cursor record is already fetched and can't be used again.

My question is how do you overcome this issue so that the cursor can be fetched again?

Comment: you can fetch data from the cursor only once. afterwads you have to reopen the cursor

Comment: From that brief outline it looks like you *might* be able to swap your loops around, but it really depends what processing you're doing. Other options include passing the cursor statement so you can re-execute it, which might be expensive and slow; or loading the cursor into a PL/SQL table so you can iterate over the results multiple times. But it depends what you're doing...

Comment: Why do you need to run the same query multiple times? Does your processing modify the data, so the next iteration needs to query to see the new data? Why not load the data into an array in memory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cursor to do your inner loop like this :

```
cursor c_1  as 
   select ...
     from ..
    where ...

rec  c_1%rowtype;

begin 

for rec in c_1 loop 
 ...
end loop;
end;
```